# how to list out test cases php query

Tags: php

I am new to Php Unit testing. I was given with 1 task. I was asked  to list out all possible test cases in my php project. May I know what exactly it mean? I had little knowledge test cases. I am not asking regarding unit testing. But asking regarding my task query.

**for eg:**

```
function1($x,$y){

$z = 'hello';
return $z;
}
```

**Should I list out possible test cases as below?**

```
function1() - takes 2 parameters ( String and Integer ) and expected output is String?
```

Comment: please explain more...

Comment: @Kiyarash May I know what you didnt understood?

Comment: What do you mean by “list out”? In a perfect world, you would strive for maximum *code coverage*, i.e. every logical expression in every (public) method of every class is tested to work. This means, “all possible test cases” would be a set of unit tests that give you 100% coverage (which btw you’ll never have in the real world.)

Comment: Maybe you could do the following: Read the following tutorial https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-introduction-to-phpunit/ (very helpful for beginning PHP unit testing), then ask your question again.